# OpenProcess: Is it possible to get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED for PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION but not for SYNCHRONIZE?

Tags: c, winapi, process

I'm using `OpenProcess` to get the process handle from a PID.
The two tasks the function should do is:

- must have: wait for the process termination, done with `WaitForSingleObject (process, INFINITE)`
- if possible: get exit code, done with `GetExitCodeProcess (process, &ret)`

**Question**: Is it possible to get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` for `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` but not for `SYNCHRONIZE`? If yes: which scenario?

My full code for reference:

```
/* wait for a pid to end and return its exit code
   error codes are returned as negative value
*/
int
waitpid (const int pid)
{
    int status = 0;
    HANDLE process = NULL;
    DWORD ret;

    /* windows will wait for the own process to end... abort */
    if (pid == _getpid ()) {
        status = 0 - ERROR_INVALID_DATA;
        return status;
    }
    /* get process handle */
    process = OpenProcess (SYNCHRONIZE | PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, pid);
    /* if we don't get access to query the process' exit status try to get at least
        access to the process end (needed for WaitForSingleObject)
    */
    if (!process && GetLastError () == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) {
        OpenProcess (SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pid);
        status = -2;
    }
    if (process) {
        /* wait until process exit */
        ret = WaitForSingleObject (process, INFINITE);
        if (ret == WAIT_FAILED) {
            status = 0 - GetLastError ();
        /* get exit code, if possible */
        } else if (status != -2) { 
            if (!GetExitCodeProcess (process, &ret)) {
                status = 0 - GetLastError ();
            } else {
                status = (int) ret;
            }
        }
        CloseHandle (process);
    } else {
        status = 0 - GetLastError ();
    }
    return status;
}
```

(if you have any comments to the code: use the comments and share your thoughts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, this is possible, because `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` and `SYNCHRONIZE` absolute independent access. however before open process - you need (if possible) enable `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` - with this privilege you can open any process (except system protected) independent from process DACL. howver even protected processes can be opened with  `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`

i do fast check for process access mask on win 10 (1607)

```
----------------------
0000000000000004 System

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000110 smss.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000170 csrss.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 00020C79 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM

----------------------
00000000000001B4 wininit.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000001C0 csrss.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 00020C79 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM

----------------------
0000000000000210 winlogon.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
000000000000025C services.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
000000000000026C lsass.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000002B4 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-42363 LogonSessionId_0_42363
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000002F0 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-63646 LogonSessionId_0_63646
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000354 dwm.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-90-0-1 DWM-1
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM

----------------------
00000000000003A8 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-67924 LogonSessionId_0_67924
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000003B0 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-72026 LogonSessionId_0_72026
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000003D8 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-72302 LogonSessionId_0_72302
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000003F0 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-75312 LogonSessionId_0_75312
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000184 WUDFHost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-84-0-76843-0-0-0
0 00 00000400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000314 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-78668 LogonSessionId_0_78668
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000004BC svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-84911 LogonSessionId_0_84911
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000004C4 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-86762 LogonSessionId_0_86762
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000528 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-89099 LogonSessionId_0_89099
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000005A0 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-92315 LogonSessionId_0_92315
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000718 svchost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-136688 LogonSessionId_0_136688
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000444 WmiPrvSE.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-144257 LogonSessionId_0_144257
0 00 00100001 S-1-5-5-0-63646 LogonSessionId_0_63646
0 00 00100000 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM

----------------------
00000000000006E0 dllhost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-146109 LogonSessionId_0_146109
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
0000000000000844 VSSVC.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-157627 LogonSessionId_0_157627
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000008E8 sppsvc.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-279111 LogonSessionId_0_279111
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000008B4 WmiPrvSE.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00100001 S-1-5-5-0-63646 LogonSessionId_0_63646
0 00 00100000 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM

----------------------
000000000000092C WmiApSrv.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-5-0-306945 LogonSessionId_0_306945
0 00 00001400 S-1-5-32-544 Administrators

----------------------
00000000000009AC sihost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-21-1621835565-972595261-354493311-1001 Kelly
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-5-0-315893 LogonSessionId_0_315893

----------------------
0000000000000A64 taskhostw.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-21-1621835565-972595261-354493311-1001 Kelly
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-5-0-315893 LogonSessionId_0_315893

----------------------
0000000000000A38 explorer.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-21-1621835565-972595261-354493311-1001 Kelly
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-5-0-315893 LogonSessionId_0_315893

----------------------
0000000000000808 RuntimeBroker.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-21-1621835565-972595261-354493311-1001 Kelly
0 00 00100001 S-1-5-5-0-63646 LogonSessionId_0_63646
0 00 00100000 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM

----------------------
0000000000000E74 SppExtComObj.Exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-20 NETWORK SERVICE
0 00 00100001 S-1-5-5-0-63646 LogonSessionId_0_63646
0 00 00100000 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM

----------------------
0000000000000F88 audiodg.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-80-2676549577-1911656217-2625096541-4178041876-1366760775 Audiosrv
0 00 00001000 S-1-5-11 Authenticated Users

----------------------
0000000000000BB8 backgroundTaskHost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-21-1621835565-972595261-354493311-1001 Kelly
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-5-0-315893 LogonSessionId_0_315893
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-15-2-1861897761-1695161497-2927542615-642690995-327840285-2659745135-2630312742

----------------------
0000000000000FB0 conhost.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-32-544 Administrators
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00121411 S-1-5-5-0-315893 LogonSessionId_0_315893
```

look for example on

```
0000000000000E74 SppExtComObj.Exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-20 NETWORK SERVICE
0 00 00100001 S-1-5-5-0-63646 LogonSessionId_0_63646
0 00 00100000 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
```

say SYSTEM have `SYNCHRONIZE` (0x00100000) but have not `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` (0x1000) or another example

```
00000000000008B4 WmiPrvSE.exe

T FL AcessMsK Sid

0 00 001FFFFF S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 00 00100001 S-1-5-5-0-63646 LogonSessionId_0_63646
0 00 00100000 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
```

**EDIT**

demo test on win 8.1 
i enable `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` and try open processes with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|SYNCHRONIZE`
i success open **ALL** processes in system, including protected
when i try open with PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION i got errors for next processes:

```
c0000022 0000000000000004 System
c0000022 0000000000000138 smss.exe
c0000022 00000000000001A8 csrss.exe
c0000022 00000000000001EC csrss.exe
c0000022 0000000000000244 services.exe
c0000022 00000000000005B8 sppsvc.exe
```

all this is windows protected processes.
now i test with open disabled `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE`. result say by self

----------- try open with PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION

```
c0000022 00000000000001A8 csrss.exe
c0000022 00000000000001EC csrss.exe
c0000022 000000000000033C dwm.exe
c0000022 00000000000005D0 WUDFHost.exe
c0000022 00000000000007E4 WUDFHost.exe
```

----------- try open with SYNCHRONIZE

```
c0000022 00000000000001A8 csrss.exe
c0000022 00000000000001EC csrss.exe
c0000022 00000000000002A4 svchost.exe
c0000022 00000000000002C8 svchost.exe
c0000022 0000000000000320 svchost.exe
c0000022 000000000000033C dwm.exe
c0000022 0000000000000358 svchost.exe
c0000022 0000000000000390 svchost.exe
c0000022 00000000000003CC svchost.exe
c0000022 00000000000001E0 svchost.exe
c0000022 00000000000005D0 WUDFHost.exe
c0000022 00000000000007F0 svchost.exe
c0000022 00000000000005B8 sppsvc.exe
c0000022 00000000000007E4 WUDFHost.exe
```

so fill different with and without `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE`

however i not catch case when can open with `SYNCHRONIZE`, but cannot with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`

Comment: Aren't the process access masks just the requested rights? It's obviously that they can be requested without the other but the question is about: when I *request* the rights, is it possible that I can get `SYNCHRONIZE` but not `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`?

Comment: `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` sounds like overkill - I just want to wait and get the exit status, not change the process' memory content.
I further assume (but may be wrong) that `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` likely gets UAC up - and the process that uses the function is in nearly all cases a command line tool and often in background.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - i open process tokens and dump DACL from it. it what he grant to caller. `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` this is not overkill but mandatory, when you try open process/tread. try enable it and view different!

Comment: @Simon, no, those are the Access Control Lists, that control what access users have to the process.  Same as the permissions on a file.  If your process doesn't have debug privilege, it simply isn't allowed to see the exit code of those processes.  (Obviously, a non-privileged program shouldn't be allowed to see exit codes for other people's processes.)

Comment: (If the end user wants to use a command-line tool with admin privilege, they should start an elevated command prompt.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston - really effect have are `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` enabled in token. not just exist (usually admin, not restricted by UAC have it) but need be enabled. easiest way use `RtlAdjustPrivilege(SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE, TRUE, FALSE, &b);` but this is undocumented. documented way use `OpenProcessToken` + `AdjustTokenPrivileges`

Comment: As RbMm says, you must enable the privilege in order to make use of it.  Incidentally, if you want the utility to work correctly regardless of whether it is running elevated or not , you can just attempt to enable `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` but not worry about whether or not the attempt succeeded.  If the user already has the necessary access to the target process, debug privilege isn't needed, and if the process is running elevated, debug privilege will give them access to every process, even ones with weird permissions.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - i edit post - add more info. when `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` enabled i open **ALL** process in system with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|SYNCHRONIZE` however when it disabled - i cannot open many processes

Comment: Thanks, this all helps a lot. As your edit has "however i not catch case when can open with `SYNCHRONIZE`, but cannot with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION`" I suggest to change your original answer "Yes it possible to get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` for `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` but not for `SYNCHRONIZE`".

Comment: @SimonSobisch - not it really possible because how i say this is independent access. that i not catch this situation in one concrete test under one concrete account not prove that this can not be

Comment: I've decided that in my concrete case (a COBOL process asking for another process' end) I'll not use `SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE` (which likely will be handy in other cases).
I'm still marking your answer as working because it answers both the original question and give additional answer.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - i for test create notepad.exe with `SYNCHRONIZE` granted to `Everyone` and no any additional access. then try open this process. as expected i can open it only with `SYNCHRONIZE` and fail with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` (with no debug privilege of course). however this is synthetic case.

Comment: @SimonSobisch - however SE_DEBUG_PRIVILEGE not only for debugging (in narrow sense) used. if we worked with another process/threads this is almost mandatory thing